# getting inputs data from previous pages in react by using useForm

Tags: reactjs, use-form

I'm building a Reactjs website that has three pages of inputs the last page should have all the data entered in the previous pages it will be a summary of the data

for the first three pages, I have been using useForm register and handle submit in order to show the data in the console log

now I want to gather all the data on one page and it should be displayed on the last page, not in the console log

how can I achieve this by using useForm?

Comment: How do you move through the three pages? Are you using `Link`, for example?

Comment: no, im using router

Comment: I mean, how does the user get to the second page after submitting the form on the first page? Having a `Link` on the page for them to click through is one option, and using a `<Redirect>` to take them to the next page automatically after the form submission is another. How are you doing it?

Comment: no i havne used Link
i used normal routing 
<Route exact path="/">
          <Home nexPageLink={"/page1"} />
        </Route>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use React context and save all the data in it and at last screen fetch data and display it . You can use redux as well.

Comment: do u have any video that can be useful for my case?

Comment: You can start with this . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc

you can find bunch of videos on youtube .

Idea is to save the data for all pages at one place in application and then use it at the last page .

You can use this approach as well 
https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/08/how-to-pass-data-when-navigating-programmatically-with-react-router/#:~:text=To%20pass%20data%20when%20navigating%20programmatically%20with%20React%20Router%2C%20we,color%3A%20'green'%20%7D%20%7D)%3B